# Using node-celery and it is creating too many connections

Tags: python, node.js, rabbitmq, celery

I am using [node-celery](https://github.com/mher/node-celery) to publish messages to a RabbitMQ instance (3.5.7) which then distributes messages to several python celery workers. Everything seems to work fine, but then after testing multiple times, it seems that the Socket Descriptors are filling up thus rejecting more connections. My guess is that the connections should be closing, but they are not.
[image]

Here is my Node.js code that sends to the corresponding routes. I tried adding `client.end` at one point but it wouldn't even send the message.

```
// Initialize connection to rabbitmq
var client = celery.createClient({
    CELERY_BROKER_URL: config.rabbitmq.connection,
    CELERY_ROUTES: config.rabbitmq.routes,
    IGNORE_RESULT: true
});

//send the message to the worker
client.on('connect', function () {
    var calculateTotal = client.createTask("calculateTotal\.run");
    var emailUser = client.createTask("emailUser\.run");
    var subscribeToMailing = client.createTask("subscribeToMailing\.run");

    calculateTotal.call([messageToRabbit]);
    emailUser.call([messageToRabbit]);
    subscribeToMailing.call([messageToRabbit]);
});
```